# How many possible color combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I have a unusual shape like this.

[image: target image to be colored]

I want to color its squares with 3 colors which no two adjacent(in vertical or horizontal) squares take the same color.

How should I solve such problems? Please give me a clear solution for given shape.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Picture isn't working for me.

Comment: @5xum Image has also uploaded [here](http://emadpres.gigfa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/squre.jpg)

Comment: I think the answer is 17952, let me check a few things.

Comment: @ypercube I need a solution. (I want to learn to think correctly but I didn't see this type of question full answer yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the 4 squares that are connected to only one other square, you are left with a rectangular 3x4 grid.

The number of 3-colourings of rectangular grids (divided by 3) is given in integer sequence **[A078099](https://oeis.org/A078099)**:

So, for the 3x4 grid, the answer is: $ 3 T(3,4) = 3 * 374 = 1122$

Now for the 4 extra squares, it's easy to see that for any of them, there are exactly 2 possibilities. So, the final answer for the specific grid is:

$ 2^4  1122 = 17952 $

Comment: Can you please add a solution for `The number of 3-colourings of rectangular grids` part as well as last part of your answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed formula for `T(n,m)`.

Answer (score -1):

overlay the pattern with a chess board to see how you can do it with *two* colours. Then in order to use three colours repaint one of the squares.

Comment: How is this helpful? There are only 2 ways of painting with two colors, and not all three-color paintings can be obtained by simply repainting one of the squares...

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more about how third color impact ?

Answer (score -1):

Hagen von Eitzen's answer seems valid and correct to me, but I will try to put my spin on it.

Look at the diagonals on a chess board. Notice that they are white, then black, then white, then black, ....

If you want to instead use 3 colors, you can do it like this.

Color the diagonals in this way:
Diagonal 1: Color 1
Diagonal 2: Color 2
Diagonal 3: Color 1
Diagonal 4: Color 3

Repeat this pattern for all of the diagonals. Tada!

[image]

Comment: you use this pattern: ABAC-ABAC... How it helps ? Why you didn't use ABC-ABC... I'm still confused. Give me starting point to think on answer (I think this question should be categorized in Hard questions)

Comment: :) As you play around with it, you will realize that there are a bazillion ways to do this. I chose one as an example. You could also do it with the ABC-ABC pattern as you pointed out.

Comment: But You didn't mention how should I count all these "bazillion ways" in an structural way :((

Comment: You never asked. Your question was "How should I solve such problems? Please give me a clear solution on given shape for your description."

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. :D But in "How should I solve such problems", `Problems` refer to title of whole question: `How many possible color combinations?`. It's nice to complete your answer by adding counting strategy.

Comment: You could write a program to loop through all 3^16 possibilities, and count the ones that meet your criteria. Or are you looking for a formula?

Comment: I wish I could but this is a sample question for my discrete math exam and I think computer is forbidden during exam :D

Comment: You may have better luck if you put the question you are asking in the actual question, and use the title to describe the topic. For example "Ways to paint a grid with 3 colors" for the title. It appears that some people (myself included) don't look back at the title after we click on it to open the question.